# Is the video tag already a WebComponent?

Tags: html, web-component

I am studying the topic WebComponent and by chance I came across a video tag. And for me it looks like this is a WebComponent in which you pass the video source via slots.

**Question 1:** Is this correct?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**Question 2:** What other native WebComponents are available?

Comment: Nope. You cannot say that that `video` is native web component just because it uses shadow DOM. It is up to browser on how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

[The video element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-video-element) is defined in the core HTML specification (as is [the source element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element)).

[Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) are a collection of technologies used to extend HTML (with custom elements).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but...

The `<video>` Element is built (by Browser vendors) using Web Component technology; you can tell by the shadowRoot it has.

[image]

And your code example, that shows how to use the `<video>` tag, using Web Components syntax, where lightDOM is being *reflected* to shadowDOM (but the `<source>` tag is a standard HTML5 tag, not a Custom Element.

Same applies to some other "complex" elements; like text inputs.

But; you have to make a distinction between **User-Agent** Web Components.

And **"UserLand"** Web Components created with the CustomElements API

[image]

Note *your* Custom Element indicates an "open" (or "closed") shadowRoot; NOT (user-agent)

So in practice you can't do anything with this knowledge. Other then tell everybody "Web Components" have been around for ages.

As for creating tags; you are not bound to Custom Elements; see my blog post: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-components-using-unknownhtmlelements-for-better-semantic-html-5d8c

Comment: Are you  not able to copy the text into the answer as instructed?